# SelectAll on a datagridCell when gained focus

Tags: wpf, vb.net, datagrid, selection

I have a vb.net datagrid which is autogenerated.
I want that when I select a cell for editing it selects all the content from that particular cell. It shoud work for both selecting via mouse click or using the tab key.
Textboxes for example have a selectAll() method which does that.
So how does it work with cells in a datagrid?

Comment: ***And***... what have you tried and what is not working? Please show us so we can help you find the issue.

Comment: Two things were not working:
1. I didn't know for which event I should make a handler
2. How to select all the cell property
Now I found a solution myself:

 Private Sub BeginEditCell(sender As Object, e As DataGridPreparingCellForEditEventArgs) Handles dgv.PreparingCellForEdit
  CType(e.EditingElement, TextBox).SelectAll()
 End Sub `code`